# Express a number in the form $a + b\sqrt{c}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I have looked into solutions of completing the square however the only example questions I can find are such as $$4x^2 – 2x – 5$$ and so on.

In an exam coming up I will have a question like this :

Given that c = 13, find the values of a and b below :

$$\sqrt{1573}(6-\sqrt{5200}) = a + b\sqrt{c}$$

I know that I have to simplify the numbers into their primes to begin with but how do I do that ?

Comment: I looked for tags saying "completing the square" and "square root" but there aren't any, what would you recommend ?

Comment: Your problem is that this is "simplifying radicals" (or some similar name) not "completing the square". That is why you are not finding the methods you need. You are looking for the wrong thing.

Comment: My apologies, on the interactive online exam (I get 5 attempts) it says I need to look into factoring quadratics by completing the square in order to complete the question

Comment: Something is wrong there, because, no you don't. This does not require factoring of quadratics at all. First you have to simplify the two square roots (see Bernard's post), then use the distributive law to multiply out the expression. The result of that multiplication is exactly what you need.

Comment: I will explain this to my tutor and hopefully it will be resolved for future students :) thank you very much for your help, I will look into simplifying square roots and the distributive law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do (directly) with quadratic equations.

**Hint:**

$1573=11^2\cdot 13$, $\;5200=20^2\cdot 13$.

*Some details:*
$$\sqrt{1573}(6-\sqrt{5200})=11\sqrt{13}(6-20\sqrt{13})=66\sqrt{13}-220\cdot\sqrt{13}^2=\underbrace{-2860}_{\vphantom{b}a}+\underbrace{66}_b\sqrt{13}.
$$

Comment: I appreciate your help but I have hardly any knowledge in this area of math, could you please explain in simpler terms how you have gotten from the question to the stage you have posted ? Or if you know any links to sites that can teach me would be equally as good as I haven't been able to find any that cover the question I have asked

Comment: what does $x + y\sqrt{13} = 0$ have to do with anything? However, the fractorizations of 1573 and 5200 are useful.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair: it means $1$ and $ \sqrt{13}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbf Q$. Whence you can deduce that, if $x+y\sqrt{13}=x'+y'\sqrt{13}$, then $\;x=x',\enspace y=y'$.

Comment: Which is miles above the level of the OP ...

Comment: @Paul Sinclair: The O.P. didn't mention any level. Of course this type of question is not from a graduate student…

Answer (score 0):

Starting with
$\sqrt{1573}(6-\sqrt{5200}) = a + b\sqrt{c}
$,
first,
factor the numbers
and
take any squares
out of the square roots.

Since
$1573
=11^2\cdot 13
$
and
$5200
=10^22^213
$,
this becomes
$11\sqrt{13}(6-20\sqrt{13}) = a + b\sqrt{c}
$.

By the magic of homework problems,
the values inside
the square roots are the same.

Multiplying this out,
$66\sqrt{13}-220\cdot 13 = a + b\sqrt{c}
$,
or,
rearranging,
$-2860+66\sqrt{13}
=a+b\sqrt{c}
$.
And we are done.

Comment: Brilliant ! This is exactly what I needed, stuff like this helps me get an understanding of the question efficiently, rather than wasting valuable 3 hours working out unnecessary things, that I could be spending on other questions . Really do appreciate the time you have taken to put it in simple terms for me.I'l be good at maths one day ! Thank you :)

Comment: You are very welcome. Just keep practicing. Remember that the people teaching the class are there to help you.